# Difference between "import random" and "import sys, random" in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a random name generator, but my guide book uses `import sys, random` instead of just `import random`. I tried looking at Google to see what the differences between the two imports are, but I couldn't find anything. Is there any difference between the two statements?

Comment: For what it's worth, the guide book goes against [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) import styles

Comment: It simply means `import sys` and `import random`.

Answer (score 3):

It means that in addition to importing the `random` library, they are importing the `sys` library as well, which means they are probably accessing some functions in that library. Check the entire code to see where they access it.

Answer (score 3):

Separating imports with commas as below

```py
import random, sys
```

is the same as

```py
import random
import sys
```

However, according to PEP8, it is recommended to separate your imports to ensure clarity. Moreover, in case any of the imports fail the traceback is more informative and you know exactly which library failed.

Answer (score 0):

`import sys, random` is importing 2 different modules: `sys` and `random`. However, `import random` will *only* import the `random` module. If the script in your book is importing the `sys` as well as the `random` module, it probably means it will also use system-related features from the `sys` module.

Comment: Thank you for the concise clarification.

Comment: no problem! I like to help beginners